# How to prevent shutdown after boot and hold it for 90sec?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, shutdown, systemd

I'm wondering is there a way to prevent shutting down for specified time like for example 90 sec after boot-up? *(from a remote that has shutdown now command)*

I would like the solution to be **in systemd style**.

The true problem is that when someone boots the device all starting services kicks in and for example if that person would turn off device like 1-45 sec after start all services would be fine except this one sending projector power-off signal. Signal would be sent fine of course but **it would have no effect due to projector heating state**

So therefore I want to make a delay solution, I cannot check power status of projector.

So far I ended up with really basic **sh script** that starts after `graphical.target`. It is a solution (poor one).

In addition reboot is a problem to because I do not want to power-off projector while rebooting so I don't think `ExecStop=` will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

So your system somehow automatically turns on/off the projector. You should integrate your solution with this process. Maybe the system can not only turn the projector on/off but also determine its state? That would be best.

Systemd services can take up to 90 seconds to stop by default. So you have a lot of time.

If you can determine the projector’s power state, you should change the “power off” script to wait for the projector to truly turn off, in a loop.

If you cannot determine the projector’s power state, you can record the start time when you turn the projector on. In the “power off” script you would then just `sleep` until the desired time on top has passed before sending the actual “power off” signal.

If I misunderstood and the projector is somehow doing its own thing, you can still adapt the second proposal by just delaying the system shutdown process.

Comment: that's a good idea but... will it work with systemd? I can see that it would probably work with normal script. Problem is that in one projector I can ask power state but in other two I cannot so I want to get universal solution. As addition I don't know what's the problem but if I bind a script to a power button on remote it sometimes doesn't work so I set poweroff scripts to systemd so it always execute with normal shutdown

Comment: Hm? This answer is specifically about Systemd. You create a service that is then stopped when shutting down. [`ExecStop=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=)

Comment: Oh okay. I'm trying it out right now. The way I see that and I'm trying to do is like create a target with service that ends in 30 sec after bootup and then I set all my shutdown services after that target... but I'm stuck with immediately shutdown with other services of course.